# PERL Error : Win32::OLE 0.1709) error 0x80040154: "Class not registered"

Tags: perl

I am getting this error specifically in this line:

```
# Calculate password using PwdMangler
$PwdMangler = Win32::OLE->new('PWDMangler.Mangler');
my $error1=Win32::OLE->LastError();
print "the error is $error1\n";

unless($password = $PwdMangler->Mangle($user , $password_plain))
{
 print $log_file "Error occured in PwdMangler\n";
 exit (1);
}
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
 the error is Win32::OLE
0.1709) error 0x80040154: "Class not registered"
can't call method 'Mangle' on an undefined values.
```

*Earlier this perl script was running on 32 bit server having 32 perl installed but now on 64 bit perl installed on 64bit server.

I am not able to find out what is not registered

Answer (score 0):

You don't have access to regedit?

The name must be a key under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, or it is not a registered class.

So with access to Perl, you can do this:

```
use Win32::TieRegistry( Delimiter=>"/", ArrayValues=>0 );

$diskKey = $Registry->{'Classes/PWDMangler.Mangler/'}
    or die "'PWDMangler.Mangler' is not a registered class!\n"
    ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response..i am out of office now(weekends)..i hope this will work..will let you know..

Comment: i executed the perl script with the given code..but still getting the same error..